# Ignoring option -Xprof; support was removed in 10.0

Tags: java, profiler

What is a proper replacement for the `-Xprof` flag?

Running a java program with JDK 11 with the `-Xprof` flag produces the following output:

```
Ignoring option -Xprof; support was removed in 10.0
```

Comment: I am seeing this new tool but it is not live and won't ouput to stdout: https://www.baeldung.com/java-flight-recorder-monitoring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an official (upstream) replacement, but very good nonetheless:

https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler

I found this to be the easiest and most comprehensive replacement.

Answer (score 3):

At the [list](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-deprecated-features-3745636.html#JDK-8176098) of deprecated features as of Java 9 Take a look at the description of [JDK-8176098](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8176098):

> This technology is no longer relevant and is a source of root scanning for the GC and contains bugs. We want to remove flatprofiler in JDK 10 and therefore deprecated it in JDK 9.

Clicking to the linked related report [JDK-8173715](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8173715) reveals:

> We assume that this technology is no longer in use and is a source of root scanning for the GC.

Unfortunately, there was an agreement of conclusion of removing a buggy `-Xprof` feature with an assumption that there is a minimal risk of affecting someone by its removal.

Comment: How do I replace the functionality `-Xprof` offered though?

Comment: I guess the feature was removed without any replacement or detail explanation.

Answer (score 0):

VisualVM still works. It is no more bundled with JDK 9 or later but it can be downloaded separately and it has a good CPU profiler and sampler.

Comment: Can you point to a source and show where the download  webpage is?